# Ember.js: How to view data from Ember.Map

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, nested-loops

I would like to view some contact information (name, email,...)  grouped by Department but I am unable to achieve it with Handlebars.

- Department X

  - Contact x1 info
  - Contact x2 info
  - ...
- Department Y

  - Contact y1 info
  - Contact y2 info
  - ...

I don't know how many departments I have in advance. So, in my controller I tried to load information in an Ember.Map where departments are its keys and and array with contacts' info is the value for each department. It is something like this:

```
map = Ember.Map.create();
// Load data from server into map
// m = {'Department X': [{name:'x1','email':'emailx1',...},{...}], 'Department Y':[....], ...}

{{#each department in map}}
    {{department}}
    {{#each contact in map.keys}}
        {{contact.name}} | {{contact.email}}
    {{#each}}
{{#each}}
```

An error is thrown saying that "an EmberCollectionView's content must implement Ember.Array. You passed [object Object]". Is it possible to achieve suh a task with nested data? Any help will be welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about creating a Department class like this:

```
App.Department = Ember.Object.extend({
  name: null
  contacts: null // will be an array of App.Contact
})
```

and a Contact class like this:

```
App.Contact = Ember.Object.extend({
  name: null,
  email: null,
})
```

When loading your data, you could simply build an array of departments

```
App.departments = [];

// parse the arriving json and populate the departments array
App.departments.pushObject(
   App.Department.create(
        {name: dptLoadedName, contacts: [App.Contact.create({...})]}
   )
)
```

So, in your template, you could do something like:

```
{{#each department in App.departments}}
   {{department.name}}
   {{#each contact in department.contacts}}
     {{contact.name}} | {{contact.email}}
   {{#each}}
{{#each}}
```

Comment: Perfect! While waiting for an answer I was trying exactly that and it works perfectly. I was trying to use Ember.Map because I come from Java universe and I used to achieve such a task with Map in my templates.  Thanks a million